# Is the length of a resume significant? If so, what's the best length?

Tags: resume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a 1-2 page resume recommended?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/844/why-is-a-1-2-page-resume-recommended)

I've read that a one-to-two-page resume is the best, but why? And is it significant?

I understand that employers have to read multiple resumes and they don't want to look at an four-page resume, but if it is largely a listing of previous work experiences, I feel like the employer can very easily and without much thought skip that parts he/she doesn't want to read.

Unless I'm planning to send in a 20-page resume with an analysis of my life story, is the length of my resume even something worth worrying about? If it is, how long is the optimal length?

Comment: Hi Brandon - your question was closed as a duplicate of another question we already have on the site. If you think there are some nuances to your question that make it different, please feel free to edit your question to make those more clear. If you need guidance, please ask in [meta] or [chat]. Thanks!