# European format or a single page?

Tags: resume

- It is often [advised](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/844/why-is-a-one-to-two-page-resume-recommended) that a resume **must** be a single page.
- On the other hand, the [European standard template](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/documents/curriculum-vitae) for a CV is two pages long, and it is often advised to use it.

I live in Bulgaria, Europe.

*Which of the two is more important?*

Comment: Are you applying for jobs in Europe, the USA, or somewhere else?

Comment: This needs a lot of clarity before it can be answered.

Comment: How about editing this question to ask "How can I determine whether I should use a one page resume or a two page resume?"  That would be something we could answer with facts, references, and specific expertise. Also, please add in more about the type of position you're looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Joe Strazzere: this is completely cultural, in France 1 page is the standard before you reach several years of career.

Comment: that out of the way, don't make it so terse as to be useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I don't think it is important at all for a CV to be only a single page. It's more important that all the relevant information is included.

However, recruiters and HR people often have to go through a LOT of CV's every day. To get through their first selection, you have to make sure the most important stuff is on the first page. This means some personal information, a summary of who you are and what you want/have to offer, and maybe a list of keywords describing your skills.

Then on subsequent pages you can elaborate by describining your complete work experience, and describing in some detail what you did for each job, what skills you learned and what technologies/tools you mastered.

The reason for this is that in the software business, it is not uncommon for an HR person to be given an assignment of the form "find a software engineer who knows C#". By stating on the first page that you are a software engineer, and by including C# with your skills right underneath that, you greatly increase your chances said HR person will notice you as a potential candidate, and pass you on to the next round.

Comment: Agreed - first page for skills + relevant experience, second for supplementary evidence and personal information (hobbies etc). 1 page is simply not enough to list everything for a non-trivial (eg shop floor worker where they're mainly concerned that you can hold down a job/have retail experience) CV