# Does listing every achievements in a resume / C.V helps me to land a job?

Tags: interviewing, resume, philippines

**Question:** Assuming that I achieved many things throughout my life, does listing every one of them can help me to land into my dream job?

This includes my `elementary awards`, `high school awards`, `college awards`, even `every competition that I've won`, `recognition from various persons`, `big projects that I have contributions`. Take note that it is just an example.

This question is specifically involved regarding Philippines only.

Comment: Are you really asking whether you should list the awards you achieved *in elementary school* on your CV?

Comment: @enderland being based in Europe I'd have to disagree with you on that. Generally only education, other professional qualifications and membership with professional bodies is detailed on a CV. When it comes to education it's generally only degree level upwards unless college or high school was the highest level achieved.

Comment: You're 21. If you're writing a resume/cv at 21, you haven't achieved anything useful that would take up 6 pages. Include what is relevant to the job for which you're applying and leave it at that.

Comment: What if the person reading your resume is like me, graduating summa cum laude?  You'll look like a slacker.  (BTW, that's not on my resume, because no-one cares.)

Comment: For those who down voted me, kindly comment out your reason please. Don't just down vote then leave, correct the beginners. :)

Comment: At your age I would be very surprised to see a resume longer than 1 page and I would not be impressed to see one longer than that in 99.999+% of the cases.

Comment: Nope, that is not my case, it is just an example. That's why I put "For example"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would listing every detail of achievement (which may take up to 6
>   pages) still be beneficial?

Absolutely not.

Having screened more than a few resumes, I'll try to give you some insight into the perspective of the people who have to sift through dozens (if not hundreds) of resumes and decide who's actually worth interviewing.

The things I care about are (in no particular order):

- What was the highest level of education that you completed?
- What college(s) did you attend (against each school you can list your GPA/magna cum laude status if you want, you don't really get any extra points for doing so; from where I sit, graduated is graduated)?
- How much *relevant* professional experience do you possess?
- Have you been consistently employed since graduating college?
- Have you held the majority of your previous jobs for at least one year (job-hopping sets off serious alarm bells in my industry)?
- Have you contributed to any high-profile and *relevant* open-source projects?

Anything from high school or earlier I'm not interested in (unless a high school diploma is the highest credential that you have).  It doesn't matter if you joined Mensa when you were six, that's not going to get you in ahead of anybody else.

**I'm looking for people who sound like they can fill a specific role.**  If you want to get my attention, give me things that make it clear that you understand the role and would be a good choice for it.  Customizing your resume and/or cover letter for the position you're applying for will help get you ahead of the pack.

I won't reject your submission outright if you hand me a 6-page essay filled with things that I don't consider relevant.  Or for being poorly organized, poorly formatted, or otherwise difficult to get across in 5 minutes or less.  Some other interviewers are less forgiving, however.  And the more noise you give me, the more difficult it is for me to pick up the signal.

So the 'ideal format' in almost all cases is keep your resume short and *focused to the role you're applying for*.  You generally do not need more than 2 pages.  Give me a high level overview, grouped sensibly (i.e. a brief summary of your skills and qualifications, a section for "Education", a section for "Work Experience", and so on) and against each item list a small number of achievements relevant to the position you're applying to.  Avoid going into the distant past (awards won in elementary school, for instance) unless you're having trouble filling even a single page.

Comment: This is the answer that I'am looking for. Thanks @aroth, +1 for detailed explanation + examples.

Answer (score 12):

The general advice for resumes is to keep them to being either one or two pages long, listing everything that you have done would seem to contradict that.
You can avoid taking too much space by simply mentioning that you have awards and not listing them individually or going into the specifics (e.g. how you earned them).

You also want to ensure that the things on your resume are *relevant*. Some award you got in school when you were 10 years younger is very unlikely to have any bearing on what you are doing now.

Anything non-academic can be mentioned briefly in your interests section if you have one.

In most places a resume is sent along with a covering letter so if you wish you can mention something there or if you have an interview and the topic comes up.

Finally I would say that you want to avoid mentioning your achievements in a way that comes across as bragging. This would be unlikely to make your personality seem attractive to any prospective employers.

Some questions from here that may help you: [Reducing resume size](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/794/) and [Why shorter resumes are preferred](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/844/)

Comment: +1 for the penultimate paragraph. If I saw a CV which had the same kind of attitude as the question here, it would be going straight in the bin as "bad team fit".

Comment: +1 for "avoid mentioning your achievements in a way that comes across as bragging" and applying a link.

Answer (score 6):

> Would listing every detail of achievement (which may take up to 6 pages) still be beneficial?

In an nutshell, no. I won first prize at a fancy dress party last year and my pub quiz team generally places in the top 3 each week but I'm not going to include it on my CV as it's utterly irrelevant to the person that's reading it.

Other people have already mentioned that a CV should not exceed more than 2 pages and provided links to questions that detail exactly why this is the case so no need to hash over that again.

However I think a point you need to consider is what purpose does your CV serve? It's my personal view that it is to sell yourself well enough through demonstrating the qualifications and experience to fulfill the role you're applying for.

I've worked with professionals before who have worked in the industry for over 20 years and due to the various experiences and roles struggle to comply with the '2 page rule'. As a result they tailor their CV for specific roles to ensure that the content specifically applies to the post they're applying for.

If you don't have much work experience under your belt then it is tempting to 'bulk out' the CV with awards and academic achievements. This is acceptable to some degree, but I'd want to read about those that demonstrate skills that are transferable to the workplace. If you've participated in opensource projects or university projects that allowed you to apply the theoretical knowledge you've gained through academia then tell me about those and be prepared to provide more detail in an interview.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody can stand a braggart. Don't come across as one. Your resume is not about you. It is about your prospective employer. It is about communicating effectively to your prospective employer your fitness to work for them on the basis of work experience, skills set and educational attainments and your potential as a contributor to them.

And you communicate effectively by being succinct and to the point, not by burying the unfortunate who has to read your CV under a blizzard of every award you ever got since you were five years old. When the focus of your resume is not the prospective employer but you, you are in trouble. When the focus of your resume is not on how well and how thoroughly your qualifications and credentials meet your employer's needs but on every award you received since you were in kindergarten, you are seriously off-course. Your resume is not mean to be a love epic written by yourself to yourself for yourself.

In the first company I worked for that went from startup to become the largest environmental planning firm in the New York Metro area, we made a point of hiring on potential and promoting on potential. Merit is how you kept your job on a day to day basis barring the occasional, business conditions-necessitated layoffs. Your potential to us is what you got hired on and what you got promoted on, given our ongoing high priority, urgent need to have highly talented people in our key positions. Be relevant and be on point. There is a reason why we are not interested in whatever awards you received as an overachieving five year old.

Comment: +1 simply for the mention that the resume is not about the person on it but the person reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Learning is good, continuous learning is better, but...employers generally do not care about every last award you won in grades 1-12, unless they were national-level or got coverage on state or provincial news (at minimum).

Put all of those details on your LinkedIn profile, not your resume. Your resume should be two pages maximum. (And...in the US and Canada, awards you received in grades 1-8 don't really matter career-wise, unless they're somehow related to the career field for which you're applying. (A science-fair national award winner when applying for a laboratory researcher position, for example.)